# Transfer TextField data between ViewControllers

Tags: swift, swift3, segue, ios10, textfield

I have ViewController, which has a textfield and a button. The user enters his name into the textfield and hits the DONE button. When he hits the button, he is segued to GifteeDetails, which is a different view controller. There is a label in that viewController that is supposed to display his name. But, his name doesn't show up. I don't receive an error.

Here's ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textGifteeName: UITextField!
@IBAction func toDetails(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetails", sender: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destDetails: GifteeDetails = segue.destination as! GifteeDetails
    destDetails.nametext = textGifteeName.text!
    destDetails.agetext = "\(Int(age)! - 2000 + 17)"
    destDetails.locationstext = labelGifteeLocationsPreview.text!
    destDetails.intereststext = labelGifteeInterestsPreview.text!
}
```

Here's GifteeDetails:

```
var nametext = String()
var agetext = String()
var locationstext = String()
var intereststext = String()

@IBOutlet weak var labelGifteeName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelGifteeAge: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelGifteeLocations: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelGifteeInterests: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    nametext = labelGifteeName.text!
    agetext = labelGifteeAge.text!
    locationstext = labelGifteeLocations.text!
    intereststext = labelGifteeInterests.text!
}
```

Sorry about all the !. Swift gives me an error unless I have them.

Comment: The problem is that you are doing it the opposite way. To set your textfield text property inside your GifteeDetails viewDidLoad method change `nametext = labelGifteeName.text!` to `labelGifteeName.text = nametext`, change `agetext = labelGifteeAge.text!` to `labelGifteeAge.text = agetext` and so on

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the strings `nametext` and others, which are not connected to your labels.

You need to replace this piece of code:

```
destDetails.nametext = textGifteeName.text!
destDetails.agetext = "\(Int(age)! - 2000 + 17)"
destDetails.locationstext = labelGifteeLocationsPreview.text!
destDetails.intereststext = labelGifteeInterestsPreview.text!
```

With:

```
destDetails.labelGifteeName.text = textGifteeName.text!
destDetails.labelGifteeAge.text = "\(Int(age)! - 2000 + 17)"
destDetails.labelGifteeLocations.text = labelGifteeLocationsPreview.text!
destDetails. labelGifteeInterests.text = labelGifteeInterestsPreview.text!
```

`nametext` is a `String` object, and it is different from `labelGifteeName.text` which is the `String` of the label you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

If you use segue then pls remove it, and then create action method of that button in the FirstviewController and use pushViewController to move on the SecondviewController.

**Swift 3**
Example:

```
@IBAction func toDetails(_ sender: Any)
{
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondView") as! SecondView

    UserDefaults.standard.set(self. textGifteeName.text, forKey: "savedStringKey")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc,
                                             animated: true)
}
```

In SecondView:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.labelGifteeName.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "savedStringKey")!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Update your func viewDidLoad() method in **GifteeDetailsVC** with **labelGifteeName.text! = nametext** , **labelGifteeAge.text!= agetext** instead of your code because you have already assigned the value in to strings i.e, nametext and agetext in ViewController, you need to display string value in label